# Data Grid Computed Column

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How to make a computed column in Flex datagrid? 
example:

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{ConsoleDetails}" id="datagrid">
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Absent Hrs" dataField="absentHrs"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText=Replaced Hrs" dataField="replacedHrs"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Difference" dataField="<WHAT TO PUT HERE>"/>                
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

How do I calculate the "Difference" Column (which should be difference of other two column) in this datagrid,what to put in the dataField property of this column?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take one of two approaches:

1. Create a new property on the class you are displaying in the datagrid like this:

   public function get difference() : Number {
            return replacedHrs - absentHrs;
       }

   And then set difference as the datafield of the column.
2. Alternately, create a label function which returns the difference of the two fields and set that instead of the dataField.

Comment: Well I didnt want to use either of these methods. I wanted to know if there was any built in functionality provided by datagrid for such facilitation? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the labelFunction is the built in functionality. You should use that.

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use any of these methods?  These are the proper way of doing things.  Datagrid does not do data calculations, this is not excel.